# Extracting part of a URL using RegEx

Tags: regex

I am trying to use RegEx to extract a particular part of some URLs that come in different variations. 
Here is the generic format:

```
http://www.blackpages.com/cityName-StateName/mip/part-I-want-to-extract/randomCharacters
```

sometimes that "mip" part doesn't exist and the URL looks like this:

```
http://www.blackpages.com/cityName-StateName/part-I-want-to-extract/randomCharacters
```

I started writing the following RE:

```
re.compile("blackpages\.com/.*")
```

the `.*` matches any character, Now, how do I stop when I encounter a "/" and extract everything that follows before the next "/" is encountered? This would give me the part I want to extract.

Comment: Rakesh, any more concerns? Please feel free to drop a line below my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a negated character class:

```
re.compile(r"blackpages\.com/([^/]*)")
                            ^^^^
```

The `[^/]*` will match 0+ chars other than `/`, as many as possible (greedily).

If you expect at least one char after `/`, use `+` quantifier (1 or more occurrences) instead of `*`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/47vLar/1)

[Python code](http://ideone.com/977dC5):

```
import re
rx = r"blackpages\.com/([^/]*)"
ss = ["http://www.blackpages.com/cityName-StateName/mip/part-I-want-to-extract/randomCharacters",
"http://www.blackpages.com/cityName-StateName/part-I-want-to-extract/randomCharacters"]
for s in ss:
    m = re.search(rx, s)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

Output:

```
cityName-StateName
cityName-StateName
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using capturing groups with that to extract only that part ?